# Как написать робота на Java?

Tags: java, робототехника

Меня этот вопрос мучает ещё с того, как начинал учить `Java`. Код на `Java` работает везде где есть машина `JVM`? Тогда как её залить в робота? А если прикрутить ему руку и реализовать её подъём/опускание, то как через код это делать? Что насчёт мат. платы? Самому собирать?

Это.. вообще возможно?

Comment: Что такое "ваш" робот? Это какая-то определенная железка или вы абстрактно спрашиваете?

Comment: Конечно, железка.

Comment: Может быть вы уточните какая именно, какой процессор и т.п.?

Comment: Мне это как раз и интересно, где найти детали и как его собрать?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Зря минусуют. Тема вообще-то интересная.

Никто же не мешает вам засунуть мат.плату/ЦП/ОЗУ в коробку из под обуви, прикрутить её к машинке, отнятой у маленького сына и сделать из этого робота в домашних условиях. Соответственно установить Винду/Линух + Java.

Ну а если серьёзно, для роботов обычно используют [микроконтроллеры](http://www.robototehnika.ru/e-store/catalog/195/), сочетающие в себе мат. плату, ЦП, ОЗУ, ПЗУ, интерфейсы ввода и вывода. Только в основном у них свои системные языки.

Другой вариант - не просто контроллеры, а [микрокомпьютеры](http://www.3dnews.ru/906977). Суть та же, но появляется возможность использовать высокоуровневые языки программирования.

[Вот](http://www.proghouse.ru/article-box/55-lejos-ev3) кстати пример робота, программируемого на JAVA.

Comment: Воу! Спасибо за статью, не нашёл сам )

Comment: как вариант можно посмотреть в сторону Arduino + Java